# PowerBI - Comparing two sets of data on timestamp

Tags: datetime, timestamp, powerbi, overlap

I am trying to compare two sets of data that share similarities. They don't have all the same columns, but I only need to compare the employee id, start time, and end time. I have made a join table on the employee id. Really, I need to see if the start and end times from both tables overlap with each other.

Here is data from Dataset 1:

```
Emp ID |    Start time      |     End Time
test-a | 11/14/2019 6:48 AM | 11/14/2019 7:35 AM
test-a | 11/14/2019 9:02 AM | 11/14/2019 11:46 AM 
test-a | 11/14/2019 1:00 PM | 11/14/2019 2:00 PM 
test-a | 11/14/2019 5:00 PM | 11/14/2019 9:15 PM
```

Here is data from Dataset 2:

```
Emp ID |    Start time      |     End Time
test-a | 11/16/2019 4:48 AM | 11/16/2019 7:35 AM 
test-a | 11/17/2019 9:02 AM | 11/17/2019 9:46 AM
test-a | 11/14/2019 7:00 PM | 11/14/2019 8:00 PM 
test-a | 11/14/2019 5:00 PM | 11/14/2019 9:15 PM
```

Desired output

```
Emp ID |  Start time        |        End Time     |   
test-a | 11/14/2019 5:00 PM | 11/14/2019 9:15 PM  | 
test-a | 11/14/2019 7:00 PM | 11/14/2019 8:00 PM  |
test-a | 11/14/2019 5:00 PM | 11/14/2019 9:15 PM  |
```

Can someone help with this in PowerBI? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were understanding the question correctly, time overlap can be defined as below.

```
Given two time periods starting and ending at (StartTime1, End1), (Start2, End2) respectively,
time overlap is the time period (Start3, End3) if Start3 < End3,

where
    Start3 = MAX( Start1, Start2 )
and
    End3 = MIN( End1, End2 )
```

You can extract overlaps by making [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of Dataset1 and Dataset2, and comparing the rows one-by-one.

Here is an example to do that with DAX calculated table.

```
Time Overlap = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    FILTER(
        CROSSJOIN(
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                Dataset1,
                "EmployeeID1", Dataset1[EmployeeID],
                "StartTime1", Dataset1[StartTime],
                "EndTime1", Dataset1[EndTime]
            ),
            SELECTCOLUMNS(
                Dataset2,
                "EmployeeID2", Dataset2[EmployeeID],
                "StartTime2", Dataset2[StartTime],
                "EndTime2", Dataset2[EndTime]
            )
        ),
        [EmployeeID1] = [EmployeeID2]
        && MAX( [StartTime1], [StartTime2] ) < MIN( [EndTime1], [EndTime2] )
    ),
    "EmployeeID", [EmployeeID1],
    "StartTime", MAX( [StartTime1], [StartTime2] ),
    "EndTime", MIN( [EndTime1], [EndTime2] )
)
```